# Какой знак препинания нужно поставить в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

*Второй сюрприз (?) радиоуправляемая машинка.*

Comment: Зависит от контекста и авторского желания. Может стоять тире или двоеточие.

Comment: Если диминутив заменим на *модель*, слову *сюрприз* вернём смысл. Всё зависит от контекста, конечно.